Triple Schwinger integral
I'm working on a perturbative QFT problem which requires three Schwinger parametrizations; that is,
$$
\frac{1}{A^n}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\int_0^\infty dz\ e^{-A z}z^{n-1}.
$$
In the end, after taking the other integrals and simplifying, I'm left with a triple integral of the form
$$
\int_0^\infty dx\int_0^\infty dy\int_0^\infty dz\ \frac{(1+x)^{2l}y^{2m}z^{2n}}{(x+z+2)^{\alpha+l+n}(y+z)^{\alpha+m+n}}e^{-Q(x+y)},
$$
where $l$, $m$, and $n$ are nonnegative integers; $Q$ is positive; and $\alpha$ is a complex number related to the dimensionally-regularized spacetime dimension.
I'm at a loss trying to figure out how to tackle this beast. No matter which integration variable I start with, I find products of power functions, exponentials, and some generalized hypergeometric functions whose arguments are rational functions the remaining variables. I think the shifts of $+1$ within the power of $x+1$ and $+2$ within the power of $x+z+2$ are the real sources of trouble, since I can recover the expected answer as these tend respectively to $x$ and $x+z$.
For the record, the theoretical framework I'm working on reduces to $SU(N)$ Yang-Mills in the same limit, so I have a reference point in the integral
$$
\int_0^\infty dx\int_0^\infty dy\int_0^\infty dz\ \frac{x^{2l}y^{2m}z^{2n}}{(x+z)^{\alpha+l+n}(y+z)^{\alpha+m+n}}e^{-Q(x+y)},
$$

For some values of paramers the improper integral under consideration is divergent. For example, making use of Mathematica 14.0, its code a = -10^6; y = 1; x = 1; m = 3; n = 4; l = 5; b = 1; Q = 1;NIntegrate[(1 + x)^(2 l)*y^(2 m)*   z^(2 n)/(x + z + 2)^(a + b*I + l + n)/(y + z)^(a + b*I + m + n)*   Exp[-Q*(x + y)], {z, 0, Infinity}] results in $ 9.82120709080683\times 10^{29805502}+5.176852152768395\times 10^{29805502} i$.

The divergence follows from the expansion of the integrand by $z$ at infinity $$(x+1)^{2 l} y^{2 m} z^{2 n} (x+z+2)^{-a-l-n} (y+z)^{-a-m-n} e^{-\frac{i b (x+y+2 z \log (z)+2)}{z}} .$$

Of course, we cannot expect simple solution. But using your first formula applied to $A=x+z+2$ and $A=y+z$  and denoting $$\varphi_{2\ell}(s)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-sx}(1+x)^{2\ell}dx$$ which is computable if $\ell$ is a small integer, then the desired integral  is  $$I=c_1\int_0^{\infty}\varphi_{2\ell}(Q+s)s^{c_2}\left(\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^{c_3}}{(Q+t)^{2m+1}(s+t)^{2n+1}}dt\right)ds$$  The inner integral is a Kummer integral we get
$$c_4\int_0^{\infty}\varphi_{2\ell}(Q+s)s^{c_5}\left(\int_0^{\infty}\frac{u^{c_3}}{(1+u)^{2m+1}(1+\frac{Q}{s}u)^{2n+1}}du\right)ds$$
